# TLS connection timeout vs TCP connection timeout

Tags: ssl

Suppose Alice and Bob establish a TLS connection on top of TCP controlled by an attacker. I understand that if the TCP connection is closed then the TLS connection is closed too. But what would happen if the TCP connection is somehow kept alive by the attacker, but Alice has been killed. Would Bob close the TLS connection after some timeout? (assuming no Heartbeat extension).

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic timeout feature in TLS. It is up to the application. If Bob's application uses a read timeout, it will trigger, and that may cause Bob's application to close.